# Space remove from a sentence but not working

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace MyCSharpLearning
{
    class TrimMethod
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string txt = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] SpaceRemove = { ' ' };
            txt = txt.Trim(SpaceRemove);
            Console.WriteLine("Your result is: {0}", txt);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Not working..help!!!!!!

Comment: `Trim` will trim spaces without an argument.

Comment: I've run the code, it appears to work as specified in [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx). Perhaps your expectations of its functionality do not match the API?

Comment: I don't think people should downvote a question because they are new/don't understand the library. They clearly showed effort, but misunderstood how trim works.

Comment: @Gray: they showed us a huge block of code with a very vague "not working" statement...

Comment: It's unclear of what you are asking. What are you trying to accomplish with the code? Remove all spaces? Some spaces?

Comment: @Gray but they show a remarkable lack of communication. Just a code snip and "HELLLLPPPPP!". Nothing on what they'd like to achieve, what the actual output is, etc.

Comment: @user7116 You are right that it could use some explanation... especially expected output/input. But the wording seems like a non-native English speaker wrote it. Just seems harsh to downvote a new user like that. No one explained *why* they downvoted or how it could be improved.

Comment: @Xcelled194 I am just saying... the question could be improved rather than downvoted. Some edits/clarifying comments, and this question could be helpful for novices wondering why trim isn't removing ALL the spaces from their string (what it sounds like they expected).

Comment: @gray I agree, which is why I didn't down vote :P unfortunately, it's impossible to edit (for me) because I have no level of confidence that I know what the OP wants. I think that's why someone down voted instead of edited.

Comment: @user2623886 In addition to using more words in your question, you might adopt an epistemological approach in coding: Name your variables such that they make a statement about their value. In your coding, `txt` is text and then different text. It doesn't say anything, which is why no one can figure out what you are trying to do. Try `inputText = Console.ReadLine()` and `textWithAllSpacesStripped = ...`. In practice, I might use something like `cleanedText` for the latter but since you are learning—and asking a question—about removing spaces, use a name that communicates that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are calling is [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx), which does:

> Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters
>   specified in an array from the current String object.

use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) to all spaces from code

```
txt = txt.Replace(" ", "");
```

Use a Regular Expression to remove trailing spaces

```
txt = Regex.Replace(txt, "^[ \t\r\n]", "");
```

A side note:

- [String.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx)
- [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string txt = Console.ReadLine();
    txt = txt.Replace(" ","");
    Console.WriteLine("Your result is: {0}", txt);
}
```

looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**string.Trim(params char[])** will remove the characters passed only if they are at the beginning or ending of the string, not if they are in the mid of the string.

```
       string txt = Console.ReadLine();
       txt = txt.Replace(" ", "");
       Console.WriteLine("Your result is: {0}", txt);
       Console.ReadLine();
```

[string.Trim(params char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx)

> Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters
>   specified in an array from the current String object.

By the way, if you only need to remove the spaces at the begin or end of the string you don't need to specify that char array. Trim() alone removes all the whitespaces where [whitespaces are defined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx)